# displaying json data from php json_encode?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

i have this jquery code which poplautes a input selector, which should display like this:

```
$("#demo-input-pre-populated").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/", {
                prePopulate: [
                    {id: 123, name: "Slurms MacKenzie"},
                    {id: 555, name: "Bob Hoskins"},
                    {id: 9000, name: "Kriss Akabusi"}
                ]
            });
```

when i try get the vales from the database using php like this:

```
prePopulate: [
                    <?
                   $responses = array();
                    $topicJSON=getQtopics($getQ);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($topicJSON)){
                    $response = array(
                        'id' => $row['id'],
                        'name' => $row['name']

                    );
                    $responses[] = $response;
                }
                echo json_encode($responses);
 ?>
        ],
```

which displays the json data like this:

```
 prePopulate: [
         [{"id":"1","name":"Dormitree"},
         {"id":"1482","name":"carriage of goods"}]        
        ],
```

but on the `#demo-input-pre-populated"` input i get undefined, and i think its becuase php is not echoing the json propelrly, how can i fix this thanks :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look the two JS outputs, the only difference is that you have two extra enclosing square-brackets `[]` in the case where you output from PHP - so you're making an array of array of JSON objects in that case while all you need is an array of JSON objects.

Get rid of the enclosing `[]` for `prePopulate` because `json_encode` is already doing that for you:

```
prePopulate: <?
                $responses = array();
                $topicJSON=getQtopics($getQ);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($topicJSON)){
                        $response = array(
                       'id' => $row['id'],
                       'name' => $row['name']
                    );
                    $responses[] = $response;
                }
                echo json_encode($responses);
            ?>,
```

Comment: can i ask you one more question, would i able to refresh prePoplaute using jquery after a click action i.e. `$(".button").click ( //refresh prePoplaute` if you get what i mean :))

Comment: @pingpong - It doesn't look like the plugin supports this, you might check with the author or put in a feature request. If you look at the source, the `insert_token()` function inserts new tokens but I'm not proficient enough with JavaScript to figure out how (if possible) to get a reference to that function and invoke it with new values.

Answer (score 2):

Your prePopulate variable is an array containing an array of objects, but you just want it to be an array of objects.

You can either take off the [ and ] brackets before and after the PHP block, or echo this in your PHP block: `array_pop(json_decode($responses))`